# LyX only shows the 1st section

Tags: sectioning, lyx

I have a `.tex` file which consists of 4 sections. When I run it on LaTeX the result is consistent with the `.tex` file. But when I import the file using LyX, LyX only hsows the first section , the others are missing. How to fix this in LyX?

---

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\title{Olympiad Problems with Solutions}
\author{Arief Anbiya}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Algebra}

\newpage

\section{Combinatorics}

\newpage

\section{Geometry}

\newpage

\section{Number Theory}


\end{document}
```

---

When I import the above using LyX, it only shows up to `\section{Algebra}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide more actionable information about your document setup.

Comment: Please make an issue on https://www.lyx.org/trac and post the minimal example .tex file and also post the resulting .lyx file.

Comment: Works fine here, LyX 2.3.3 on Kubuntu.